# Is there a standard dimension definition for CD/DVD drive bay?

Tags: case

Probably naive, but is there a standard to mandate the dimensions of CD/DVD drive bay on a cabinet/enclosure are met?

Neither my BenQ CD Writer, nor my ASUS DVD Writer fit into the 5.25 bay of my recently purchased CC 515 cabinet[image]

Comment: strange problem.. Do you try it in another bay? And look if there is any support flap is in the way. Can you upload the pic of your case's inner side.

Comment: Thanks kaykay, and dragonlord. Turns out the support pillar to the right is defective/bent ... hence the top two bays were u/s; the bottom bay worked but it is a _very_ snug fit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_bay), the dimensions of a 5.25-inch drive are defined by the standards [SFF-8500](ftp://ftp.seagate.com/pub/sff/SFF-8500.PDF) and [SFF-8501](ftp://ftp.seagate.com/pub/sff/SFF-8501.PDF).